# I just wanted to know how to add additional packages to the preseed file?

Tags: 12.04

I am preparing my preseed file for the unattended installation of Ubuntu using a CD iso image. This is the following file:

```
### Localization
d-i debian-installer/locale string en_US

# Keyboard selection
d-i console-setup/ask_detect boolean false
d-i keyboard-configuration/layoutcode string us

### Network configuration for CDROM or USB stick only
d-i netcfg/choose_interface select auto
d-i netcfg/get_hostname string unassigned-hostname
d-i netcfg/get_domain string unassigned-domain
d-i netcfg/wireless_wep string

### Clock and time zone setup
d-i clock-setup/utc boolean true
d-i time/zone string US/Eastern

### Partitioning
d-i partman-auto/method string lvm
d-i partman-lvm/confirm boolean true
d-i partman-lvm/device_remove_lvm boolean true
d-i partman-auto/choose_recipe select atomic
d-i partman/confirm_write_new_label boolean true
d-i partman/confirm_nooverwrite boolean true
d-i partman/choose_partition select finish
d-i partman/confirm boolean true
d-i partman-lvm/confirm boolean true
d-i partman-lvm/confirm_nooverwrite boolean true
d-i partman-auto-lvm/guided_size string max

### Account setup
d-i passwd/user-fullname string Ubuntu User
d-i passwd/username string ubuntu
d-i passwd/user-password-crypted password $1$1AniiGAw$ZsUcBK840ZrkmoVIvTneP1
d-i user-setup/encrypt-home boolean false

### Apt setup
d-i apt-setup/use_mirror boolean false

### Package selection
tasksel tasksel/first multiselect ubuntu-desktop
d-i pkgsel/updatedb boolean false

### Boot loader installation
d-i grub-installer/only_debian boolean true
d-i grub-installer/with_other_os boolean true

### Finishing up the installation
d-i finish-install/reboot_in_progress note

### X configuration
xserver-xorg xserver-xorg/autodetect_monitor boolean true
xserver-xorg xserver-xorg/config/monitor/selection-method \
       select medium
xserver-xorg xserver-xorg/config/monitor/mode-list \
       select 1024x768 @ 60 Hz

////////////////////////////
```

Thanks in advance